# selecting specific cells in a column and performing an operation on the selected cells?

Tags: excel, cells

I have a long column that shows multiple values numeric and non-numeric. I want to select those non-numeric cells, which are numbers WITH letters (units) next to them, remove the letters, and subtract a value from that selected cell without touching other cells. For example, if the values of E1:E5 are 1.3kg, 3.2, 1.1kg, 1.5, 2.1kg respectively, I want to select E1,E3, and E5 and subtract 0.2 from those selected cells, so the new values will become 1.1, 3.2, 0.9, 1.5, 1.9.

Comment: filtering the column, creating a cell with the value I need to subtract, copy that, do "special past" on that column, and check "subtract". This subtracted 0.2 from the whole column! which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do this, you are going to need to create a formula in another column:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"kg","")-0.2)
```

You can then copy and paste the values back into column E.

The only other way to do this is through VBA.

Comment: Applying this formula gave me #VALUE!

Comment: @rwilson His data is dirty.  Both our solutions should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula into cell `F1` in your the spreadsheet you described above:

```
=IF(RIGHT(E1, 2)="kg", LEFT(E1, LEN(E1) - 2) - 0.2, E1)
```

You can copy this formula down the `F` column to cover the range of cells `E1:E5`.

Comment: I copied the formula to F1, dragged F1 down to F5, and I got a replica of E1:E5 in F1:F5! with no changes!

Comment: I believe you may be using Excel incorrectly.  The formula should be fine.

Comment: There could be trailing spaces in the cells.

Comment: Please update your OP with the _exact_ data you really have in your E column.

Comment: I have more than a 100 thousand rows, and the problem is exactly as I described it.

Comment: Try using the `TRIM()` function to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @rwilson, you're correct there was a space after each kg. I updated Tim's formula to =IF(RIGHT(E1, 3)="kg ", LEFT(E1, LEN(E1) - 3) - 0.2, E1), and it worked. Thanks Tim!